# how to get best fit line when we have data on vertical line?

Tags: python, linear-regression

I started learning Linear Regression and I was solving this problem. When i draw scatter plot between independent variable and dependent variable, i get vertical lines. I have 0.5M sample data. X-axis data is given within range of let say 0-20. In this case I am getting multiple target value for same x-axis point hence it draws vertical line.
My question is, Is there any way i can transform the data in such a way that it doesn't perform vertical line and i can get my model working. There are 5-6 such  independent variable that draw the same pattern. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Goal of linear regression is to find the best fit that shows minimum error. If your dataset shows a line that has vertical nature, the model obviously will fit a line that is closely vertical to the data.

Comment: In case of vertical line the error won't me minimum, even if regression draws the line. Am i right?

Comment: No brother. The error is calculated based on the data points. If you have data set with linear nature, the linear regression will always go for minimum error. Depends on data. It doesn't matter if the visual shape of the data seems more vertical or horizontal. Linear regression will always fit the shape of the data.

Comment: @IbtihajTahir common implementations of line fitting, for example RANSAC in scikits use the line model ax + b = 0. This model is flawed. Vertical lines will have a = infinite, and it will always end up returning a wrong result. So yes, a vertical line will break your code if you rely on those libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of fitting y as a function of x, in this case you should fit x as a function of y.

Comment: I didn't get it. You mean to say, i should predict independent variable based on target variable?

Comment: yes that's right - and when you have a linear model for x(y) you can invert it to get y(x). If the y are spread and the x are bunched, this should give you a better model then directly fitting y(x). See for example reference: DOI: 10.1086/169390

Comment: But in this case i have multiple features not single one. Then how can i do this?

Comment: @pygri Kindly explain how can you predict the features based on ground truth only. That doesn't even make sense.

Comment: This is not a solution. Imagine that you have both vertical and horizontal segments in your data!